# TypeScript 0.9.5 module import

Tags: typescript

My TypeScript version is 0.9.5.

I have this sctructure:

- models

  - person.ts
  - work.ts
- app.ts

In person.ts:

```
export module Model {

    export class Person {
        name: string;
        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

In work.ts:

```
export module Model {

    export class Worker {
        id: number;
        constructor(id: number) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I import this modules with one name in one variable in file app.ts?

This does not work, because of "Duplicate identifier 'M'":

```
import M = require("models/person");
import M = require("models/work");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Each external module (third for which you use require) is distinct from internal modules (module keyword).

The TS community recommends not to use internal modules (module keyword) when using external modules.

PS: I cover it in this video as well http://youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Comment: What I should do, if I want to have some module, for example Models, and some classes, for example Models.Person, Models.Work, but these classes will be described in different files? I'm using AMD module system.

Comment: If you use `grunt-ts` you can put these in a folder and then import the entire folder as : `///ts:import=foldername` See : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/issues/85 So your folder effectively becomes a `module`